# Regex match for IDN domain names

Tags: regex, idn

I want to check the domains with regex. I used this code but it doesn't work:

```
/^([^\s<>]+([^\s<>]*[^\s<>]+)?.){0,}([^\s<>]+([^\s<>]*[^\s<>]+)?){1,63}(.[^\s<>]{2,7})+$/i
```

**My domain format is:**

- `example.com`

**I don't want:**

- `www.example.com`
- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`

**At the same time**, user can add the domains;

- with 2 extension like `example.co.uk`
- as an IDN like `üüüüüü.üüü`

Comment: Clarify "it doesn't work" with examples and counterexamples, please.

Comment: users can not add two extension domains and can domains with http:// or www